# SQLite Create Table portion of the code not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to code a GPA Calculator, where it first gives the user a choice to create an account(create table in SQLite to store the data) or insert data (Query the GPA data). However, somehow, the code for creating the table doesn't seem to work. Based on the code below, when I input "create account" it should return in the terminal:

Connected to sqlite Successfully
Table created Successfully

However, it doesn't seem to, instead, it returns only "Connected to sqlite Successfully" what is the problem here?

```
import sqlite3

query = str(input("What do you want to do? (Create Account,Insert New Data) "))

sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect("SQLite_Python_Test.db")

cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
sqliteConnection.commit()
print("Connected to sqlite Successfully")

if query.lower() == "create table":
    try:
        sqlite_query_create_table = '''CREATE TABLE gpa_calc_users_test(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
            username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            password TEXT NOT NULL,
            gpa_sem1 REAL,
            gpa_sem2 REAL);'''

        cursor.execute(sqlite_query_create_table)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Table created Successfully")
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while inserting data")

    finally:
        if(sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("SQLite connection closed")
elif query.lower() == "Insert New Data":
    try:
        insert_parameters = (int(input("ID: ")),str(input("Username:     ")),str(input("Password:")),float(input("Semester 1 GPA: ")),float(input("Semester 2 GPA: ")))
        sqlite_query_insert = '''
        INSERT INTO gpa_calc_users_test
            (id,username, password, gpa_sem1, gpa_sem2)
            VALUES
            (?,?,?,?,?)
        '''
        cursor.execute(sqlite_query_insert,insert_parameters)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Query inserted Successfully")
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while inserting data")

    finally:
        if(sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("SQLite connection closed")
```

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need `UNIQUE` with a `PRIMARY KEY` - that's implied by being a PK.

Comment: Thanks for the additional help!

Answer (score 0):

> when I input "create account" it should return in the terminal:
>
> Connected to sqlite Successfully Table created Successfully

Not true. If "create table" is input, that would be the expected result. But if "create account" is entered, it will connect to the databaase, display the "connect successful" message, and finish.

And FWIW, this `elif query.lower() == "Insert New Data":` can never be true.